# Animating Blender Poses with scripting

Tags: animation, scripting, pose-mode

I am thinking of animating my pose library with blender scripting for that i been searching for video solutions but could not find something helpful. If there was any it was only moving a single bone with a script.
Is it possible to animate my pose library with blender scripting. If yes, then How?

Comment: what do you mean by 'animate pose library with scripting'?  Are you talking about assigning a pose, and setting a keyframe; then moving to a different frame, setting a different pose, and setting a keyframe; so that blender will generate f-curves to move from pose to pose?

Comment: Yes, I am talking the same. Like animating mouth shapes or Lip syncing and then implement PreAnimated Actions on different keyframes to complete the animation pipeline of a short documentary.